# Slow inputs with Vue and Vue Material

Tags: vue.js, vue-material

I'm using VueJs 2.0 with [Vue Material](https://github.com/marcosmoura/vue-material). I'm rendering a table with quite a few rows that contains multiple input fields and/or select fields (VueMaterial components).

When entering data into the inputs the components becomes quite slow. Here is a [live demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yhk1tc2v/3/) to better demonstrate the issue.

```js
Vue.use(VueMaterial);

Vue.material.registerTheme('default', {
  primary: 'indigo',
  accent: 'indigo',
  warn: 'red',
  background: 'white'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  beforeUpdate: function() {
    console.log('Rerendering');
    console.log(this);
  },
  data: {
    countries: [{
      id: "CAN",
      value: "CAN"
    }, {
      id: "UAE",
      value: "UAE"
    }, {
      id: "UK",
      value: "UK"
    }, {
      id: "USA",
      value: "USA"
    }, {
      id: "ZA",
      value: "ZA"
    }],
    tableData: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Name 1',
        number: Math.random(),
        country: 'ZA'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Not another name',
        number: Math.random(),
        country: "UK"
      }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'One more name',
        number: Math.random(),
        country: "UAE"
      }, {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Another name',
        number: Math.random(),
        country: "USA"
      }, {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Another name',
        number: Math.random(),
        country: "CAN"
      }, {
        id: 6,
        name: 'Another name',
        number: Math.random()
      }, {
        id: 7,
        name: 'Another name',
        number: Math.random()
      }, {
        id: 8,
        name: 'Another name',
        number: Math.random()
      }, {
        id: 9,
        name: 'Another name',
        number: Math.random()
      }, {
        id: 10,
        name: 'Another name',
        number: Math.random()
      }, {
        id: 11,
        name: 'Another name',
        number: Math.random()
      }, {
        id: 12,
        name: 'Name 1',
        number: Math.random()
      }, {
        id: 13,
        name: 'Not another name',
        number: Math.random()
      }, {
        id: 14,
        name: 'One more name',
        number: Math.random()
      }, {
        id: 15,
        name: 'Another name',
        number: Math.random()
      }, {
        id: 16,
        name: 'Another name',
        number: Math.random()
      }, {
        id: 17,
        name: 'Another name',
        number: Math.random()
      }, {
        id: 18,
        name: 'Another name',
        number: Math.random()
      }, {
        id: 19,
        name: 'Another name',
        number: Math.random()
      }, {
        id: 20,
        name: 'Another name',
        number: Math.random()
      }, {
        id: 21,
        name: 'Another name',
        number: Math.random()
      }, {
        id: 22,
        name: 'Another name',
        number: Math.random()
      },

    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">

  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(item, rowIndex) in tableData" :key="item.id">

        <td>
          <md-input-container>
            <md-input type="text" v-model="item.name" />
          </md-input-container>
        </td>
        <td>
          <md-select v-model="item.country">
            <md-option v-for="option in countries" :value="option.id">
              {{ option.value }}
            </md-option>
          </md-select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <md-select v-model="item.country">
            <md-option v-for="option in countries" :value="option.id">
              {{ option.value }}
            </md-option>
          </md-select>
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ item.number }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Try keeping a letter in when typing in the text input. With more rows even normal typing gets quite slow.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: those <md-select>s seem to be slowing things down. after removing them temporarily, things seems to work flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is with Vue-Material. There is already a bug logged for this. https://github.com/marcosmoura/vue-material/issues/544

Answer (score 0):

Seems like removing the second select box eases things up (see [an updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b5d86ym7/)).

Do you really need two identical select boxes?

```html
<div id="app">

  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(item, rowIndex) in tableData" :key="item.id">
        <td>
          <md-input-container>
            <md-input type="text" v-model="item.name" />
          </md-input-container>
        </td>
        <td>
          <md-select v-model="item.country">
            <md-option v-for="option in countries" :value="option.id">
              {{ option.value }}
            </md-option>
          </md-select>
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ item.number }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: This was just an example, we have multiple tables with multiple select boxes. It seems the issue is with Vue-Material. There is already a bug logged for this. [link](https://github.com/marcosmoura/vue-material/issues/544)

Answer (score 0):

a long time has passed but I think I have found a solution to make it a little better.
First you need to fork the repo otherwise you will need to create pull requests to the official repo that is more or less abandoned.
Once created the fork just open:

> vue-material/src/components/MdField/MdSelect/MdSelect.vue

Go to line 41 and remove:

```
<div v-if="!showSelect" v-show="false">
  <slot />
</div>
```

I don't understand why this, I think they wanted to cache the list in some way but this just cause to cycle options twice making the component heavier.
Especially with a lot of options.

I tested the component in several way and it seems to work fine now.

To be sincere I had to apply other fixes to make it work properly but not related to this topic.

Unfortunately the repo is abandoned, it is just code to fork to save some time but needs to be maintained and improved.

Use the less vue-material component you can.